# Delete current CommandData JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

So I'm making a Slash Command Library for JDA, and for some reason, I can't find any documentation on removing a slash command from a guild. Let me explain.

So I use `guild.upsertCommand(commandData);` to register the command. But what I want to know is if the guild has a command with that name, I want to delete that command from the guild, so that the old one and the new one aren't mixed up.

Cheers,
Agent

Comment: MinnDevelopment looking at you to answer this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just realized after looking through the api you can iterate through the commands and get the one you want to delete it.

Comment: (Make sure to solve your own awnser, so this is counted as a awnsered post)

Comment: oh yea, forgot that existed